# how to translate this PostgreSQL query into activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

SELECT id, (SELECT SUM(s) FROM UNNEST(invested) s) as temp from times ORDER BY temp DESC NULLS LAST;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass raw SQL to `#select` in order to select dynamic/calculated values. Untested, but see if something like this works:

```
tasks = Task
  .select('id, (SELECT SUM(s) FROM UNNEST(priorities) s) AS temp_sum')
  .order(temp_sum: :desc)

# tasks.first.id => the Task ID
# tasks.first.temp_sum => the SQL-calculated value
```

Postgres orders nulls last by default, so the `NULLS LAST` isn't strictly necessary. Though of course you could keep it in if you want to be fully explicit: `.order('temp_sum DESC NULLS LAST')`.

It's not an issue for this exact use case, since you're not passing in any user-inputted values, but just as a general warning: always be careful about SQL injection vulnerabilities when passing in raw SQL! Because Rails won't be able to perform all of its input-sanitizing magic when you just pass in raw strings.

Comment: Thanks, but  NULLS LAST isn't the default it seems. version 12.2

Comment: Oh, I guess the NULLS LAST default has changed then, my bad. As to the addition of the `.where`: that's odd it breaks things, I'm not sure exactly what's going on. To help debug, what's the output of tacking a `.to_sql` at the end of the query and printing it?